# Add to container's /etc/hosts using Fig?

Tags: docker, fig

I'm trying to configure `fig` so that I can connect to my database server without specifying a fully qualified domain name.  The database is running on bare metal (not in docker).  On the host, `glinda.local` is specified in `/etc/hosts` and I'd like the container to mimic this behavior (though not rely on the host's config).

I found [this suggestion](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/754#issuecomment-74203777) on github, but it fails since `/etc/hosts` is on a read-only file system.

So the question remains, how can I add `glinda.local` from `fig.yml` to `/etc/hosts` inside my docker container?

Comment: Linking the container will also set a hosts entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Docker v1.3.1 (I think) you have available the option `--add-host` in `docker run`. Unfortunately this options has not been merged to fig:master yet, but there is [a PR with it](https://github.com/docker/fig/pull/848). When merged (or using that branch) you should be able to use it in this way:

> extra_hosts
>
> Add hostname mappings. Use the same values as the docker client
>   --add-hosts parameter.

```
> extra_hosts:
>  - docker: 162.242.195.82
>  - fig: 50.31.209.229
```

> An entry with the ip address and hostname will be created in
>   /etc/hosts inside containers for this service, e.g:

```
> 162.242.195.82  docker
> 50.31.209.229   fig
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think `/etc/hosts` is read-only? The following works for me with Docker 1.5:

```
$ docker run -it debian
root@0989fd55e8fa:/# echo "127.0.0.1 test" >> /etc/hosts
root@0989fd55e8fa:/# ping test
PING test (127.0.0.1): 48 data bytes
56 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
56 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
^C--- test ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.068/0.073/0.078/0.000 ms
```

Are you saying this doesn't work for you? If the above works, you should be able to add what you need into an entrypoint script.